# Parallax effect on bootstrap carousel won't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

For my website I made a bootstrap carousel, with different slides which each have a parallax effect, in Every browser this works fine except Firefox.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/15977/)

```
<!--Carousel Wrapper-->
<div id="carousel-example-2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--/.Indicators-->
    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="view slidescss" style="background:url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg')no-repeat fixed center;">
                <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 class="h3-responsive">Light mask</h3>
                <p>First text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <!--Mask color-->
            <div class="view slidescss" style="background:url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(6).jpg')no-repeat fixed center;">
                <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 class="h3-responsive">Strong mask</h3>
                <p>Secondary text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <!--Mask color-->
            <div class="view slidescss" style="background:url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(9).jpg')no-repeat fixed center;">
                <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 class="h3-responsive">Slight mask</h3>
                <p>Third text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.Slides-->
    <!--Controls-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <!--/.Controls-->
</div>
```

Own CSS Classes:

```
.slidescss{
    background-size:1920px 1080px;
    width:100%;
    min-height:800px;
}
```

Try this in in any browser, and then Firefox.
In Firefox, the caption is put above the image, and either the background is white or grey. It pushes the image down. I sort of fixed this by removing the `center` attribute from `background:url()`. But it still has no Parallax effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in conflict with

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

You can remove it, than it'll work.

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/16131/

Kind regards,
Rakowu

Comment: Thanks! It's been a headache, searching the web for the possible problem.

Comment: Would you also know why my image in the carousel is pushed down in firefox when it slides? I added center to it, and this is messing up the image when the animation to slide starts. I added the `center` attribute to the `no-repeat fixed` attributes..

Comment: Could you send me a screenshot?  To reproduce your bug :)

Comment: Ok i guess i get what you mean. Use Instead of center, center top. And give it a height of for example 600px. If you making your webside responsive you can use 100vh for fullsize :)

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/19536/

<div class="view slidescss" style="background:url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg')no-repeat fixed top center;">

Comment: that works! But now they zoom in and when the sliding is done the images are the proper size, so when the sliding commences the images zoom in like it's trying to fill the whole page, and then it reset's itself to the appropriate size. Might you know something about that? 

Firefox version:Firefox Quantum 59.0.2 (64-bits)

[Should be](https://imgur.com/5ljqvV0) 
and
[Zoomed in](https://imgur.com/PO9iARI)

Comment: i guess it happens  because the image until the slide ends doesn't know its width. Ist he width of the image beeing calculated with javascript? Try giving the element (with the image background) a width (try it first px based). If it does what it should do, than it has a problem with the javascript or % based width

Comment: No, it's not being calculated with JS. I will try to set the image width before it's being loaded. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I've set the width of the html with CSS as 100%. I will try to set it with JS / Jquery